# Почему возникает ошибка компиляции при виртуальном наследовании?

Tags: c++, наследование, множественное-наследование

Обьясните, пожалуйста, в чем тут роль `virtual`? Если наследовать от класса `Lock` без `virtual` то код компилируется, а иначе компилятор выдает ошибу:

```
note: ‘Derived::Derived()’ is implicitly deleted because
the default definition would be ill-formed: class Derived : public Base
```

```cpp
class Base;

class Lock {
    Lock() {}
    friend class Base;
};

class Base : virtual private Lock {
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {};

int main() {
    Derived obj;
    obj.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При виртуальном наследовании порядок вызова конструкторов нарушается, и конструктор виртуального базового класса `Lock` будет вызываться классом `Derived`. Однако у класса `Derived` нет доступа к приватному конструктору `Lock::Lock()`.

Answer (score 0):

Еще есть ключевое слово final
[1]: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

**Виртуальное наследование** нужно для исключения дубликатов базового класса при *множественном* (*ромбовидном*) *наследовании* путём делегирования вызова конструктора общего класса производному. Соответсвенно, вызов конструктора `Lock` делегируется `Derived`. Но т.к. наследование приватное, т.е. все `public` и `protected` члены `Lock` становятся `private` для `Base`, включая конструкор, то у вас ошибка компиляции.

Вот как обычно выглядят вызовы конструкторов для `Derived` в *member initializer list*:

```cpp
class Base {};
class InterA : public virtual Base {};
class InterB : public virtual Base {};


class Derived : public InterA, public InterB {
public:
    Derived()
        : Base{}
        , InterA{}
        , InterB{}
        , data_{}
    {}

private:
    int data_;
};
```